# Date data won't populate from form in Make Table Query (Access)

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that I am trying to use to fill in data for a make table query. All the data from the form is pulled successfully except for the date. I have a date picker in the form to select a date.

I've tried adding ".text" after the [Date] with no success. I don't know why it's not pulling the date.

Here's the SQL from the query:

```
 SELECT [Forms]![FrmMakeCert]![EmpName] AS EmpName, [Forms]![FrmMakeCert]![TrainerName] AS Trainer, [Forms]![FrmMakeCert]![AdminName] AS Admin, [Forms]![FrmMakeCert]![Level] AS [Level], [Forms]![FrmMakeCert]![Age] AS Age, [Forms]![FrmMakeCert]![Date] AS [Date] INTO ModuleCert;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CDate() function works for me:

`SELECT ..., CDate([Forms]![FrmMakeCert]![Date]) AS [Date] INTO ModuleCert;`